# How to clear table data when the default value of the dropdownlist is being selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How do i clear my table data in my webapp whenever i selected a default value that i have inserted into my dropdownlist?

I have a dropdownlist box with 3 options

1. SelectPoliceReportID (Default Value)
2. PoliceReportID123 (Database Value)
3. PoliceReportID456 (Database Value)

When i select the DB values, they will display out individual DB values, however when i select the default value, the previously clicked DB value information will still remain on the table data.

This is my pageload code where the policereportID will be displayed

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select pr.policereportid from PoliceReport pr, MemberReport mr where pr.memberreportid=mr.memberreportid and mr.caseprogress='completed'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DDLCase.Items.Add(dr["policereportid"].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

In my previous question, I'm only able to  clear my data from my gridview by inserting the following codes after my databind

```
     DDLCase.Items.Clear();
     DDLCase.DataSource = ds2;
     DDLCase.DataTextField = "memberreportid";
     DDLCase.DataValueField = "memberreportid";
     DDLCase.DataBind();
     DDLCase.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Member Report ID", ""));
     DDLCase.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Here is my dropdownlist

```
protected void DDLCase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select lro.fullname, lro.contact, mr.typeofcrime, mr.location,mr.crdatetime, pr.policeid, pr.prdatetime, pr.policereport, pr.image1, mr.citizenreport from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro where pr.policereportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedValue + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and lro.username=mr.username and mr.caseprogress='completed'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            lblFullName.Text = dr["fullname"].ToString();
            lblContact.Text = dr["contact"].ToString();
            lblTOC.Text = dr["typeofcrime"].ToString();
            lblLocation.Text = dr["location"].ToString();
            lblCRDT.Text = dr["crdatetime"].ToString();
            lblPicture.Text = dr["image1"].ToString();
            lblAssign.Text = dr["policeid"].ToString();
            lblPRDT.Text = dr["prdatetime"].ToString();
            lblCR.Text = dr["citizenreport"].ToString();
            lblPR.Text = dr["policereport"].ToString();
        }

        con.Close();

    }
```

Source code for my table. i DID NOT use the asp:table. I programatically added the table into the source code.

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 576px;">
<tr>
<th style="width: 595px; height: 49px;">Full Name :</th>
<td style="width: 533px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="height: 49px; width: 134px">Contact :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblContact" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 595px">Location :</th>
<td style="width: 533px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="width: 134px">Type of Crime :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblTOC" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 595px">Picture : </th>
<td style="width: 533px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblPicture" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="width: 134px">Citizen Report Date &amp; Time :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblCRDT" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 595px">AssignTo :</th>
<td style="width: 533px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblAssign" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="width: 134px">Police Report Date &amp; Time :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblPRDT" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 595px; height: 100px;">Citizen Report :</th>
<td colspan="4" style="height: 100px" text-align:"left">
  <asp:Label ID="lblCR" runat="server" Text="" style="display: block; text-align:  left;"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 595px; height: 135px;">Police&nbsp; Report :</th>
<td colspan="4" style="height: 135px" text-align: "left">
  <asp:Label ID="lblPR" runat="server" Text="" style="display: block; text-align:  left;"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<th style="width: 595px; height: 135px;">Official Report :</th>
<td colspan="4" style="height: 135px">
  <asp:TextBox ID="tbofficial" runat="server" Height="121px" TextMode="MultiLine"    Width="878px" ></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  <br />
  <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
        </td>
  </tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: here `table data` is the c# `datatable` or the database `datatable`

Comment: if it's a c# `DataTable` then use `table.Clear();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `DDLCase_SelectedIndexChanged`  do below

```
if(DDLCase.SelectedIndex == 0) // this is the default value 
{
            lblFullName.Text = String.Empty;
            lblContact.Text = String.Empty;
            // clear all the textboxes 
}else
{

   // your code 

}
```

Or you can hide the html table if default value selected. But you need to add id and `runat="server"` tag to your table. After that you can set `yourtable.visible =false;` by C# code

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. Managed to clear it by replacing String.Empty with "". Sorry to change your codes but it's easier for me in my opinion. But nevertheless, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all label text then use `SelectedIndex` like

```
if(DDLCase.SelectedIndex == 0) // default value 
{
   foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
   {

    if (ctl is Label)
      { 
       ctl.Text = "";
      }

   }
}
   else
      {
       // code 
      }
```

But If you want to Clear `DataTable` the you have to use

```
 DataTable.Clear();
```

Method (System.Data) to clear data table.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear.aspx)

Comment: Sorry. I just realised i left out something very important. I did not use the asp:table. I added my own html table. So i'm wondering if the method works similiarly.

Comment: if you are using `Html` table then `Empty` the controls value of `Label` through looping as i did when you select default value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found a suitable answer and i have ticked it :D